# How to fix this stack overflow in this tkinter/exec()/cffi combination?

Tags: python, python-cffi, python-exec

I have a Python-powered DSL which I execute through `exec()`. This DSL includes a native function calls through CFFI.

I'm getting stack overflow (SO, you made it ungooglable!) crash when calling a native function which is just 2 C calls deep, with only a handful of `uint16_t`s allocated on a stack in each C function. Python application is a `tkinter` GUI that calls the DSL  by timer (`master.after(1000, self.tick)`) event, which might take a good portion of stack itself.

There are NO recursive calls here.

OS X 10.12.3, Python 3.6.0rc1 (v3.6.0rc1:29a273eee9a5, Dec  6 2016, 16:24:13), CFFI 1.9.1

I'm aware of `resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK, (resource.RLIM_INFINITY, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))`, but it requires a superuser privilege. I believe this is not needed, as it's not normal to only have a stack remaining for two function calls.

Could CFFI or exec() be limiting the stack size for the callee?

Function being called from DSL:

```
ffi_builder.cdef('''
//...
int FooNode_SetProperty(struct FooNode *pThis, const char *szPropertyName, int nValue);
''')

def set_channel(node, channel):
    node.SetProperty(b'channel', channel)
```

`exec` invocation code:

```
    self._globals = {
        '__builtins__': __builtins__,  
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval "If the globals dictionary is present and lacks
        # ‘__builtins__’, the current globals are copied into globals before expression is parsed."

        'run': {
            'duration': 60 * MICROS,
            'success': None
        },

        'set_channel': set_channel,
        'turn_off': turn_off,
        'turn_on': turn_on,
        'finish': finish,
        # 6 more functions here
    }

    exec(event_text, self._globals, {})
```

Apple report piece:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
[35633] stack overflow

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001003bfdd6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffe03dc787 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffe02564bb __abort + 140
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffe0256d7e __stack_chk_fail + 205
4   libmush_real.dylib          0x0000000104c4d714 send_counters_report_request + 532
```

(this thread really ends here, nothing else in Apple report)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to connect with a debugger.

The stack that has nothing after the current call is a sign that a stack was overwritten, normally via a pointer to a stack variable.